# First Android App - Can't convert EditText to integer value

Tags: android, parseint

I'm trying to write my first Android app.  It will take a number input by a user in an EditText field, convert it to an integer, then find the factors.  I want to port this from a Java program that I wrote before.  I have stubs working to the point that I have a UI, but I haven't yet ported the code that will find the factors.  I'm stuck trying to convert the EditText to an integer.  If I insert either of the following lines, the program crashes in the emulator.  Log.Cat says, "Caused by NumberFormatExcepion: Unable to parse '' as an integer."

Any suggestions are appreciated.

userNumber is the name of the value taken from the EditText field, and the EditText field is also named userNumber.  I don't know if that's bad form or not.  I want to assign the value of userNumber to the integer value userInt.  userInt will then be factored.

Either of these approaces will cause the problem:

```
userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNumber);
userInt = Integer.parseInt(userNumber.getText().toString());


Integer userInt = new Integer(userNumber.getText().toString());
```

The EditText block of XML looks like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userNumber"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Here is the relevant code from the class:

```
public class AndroidFactoringActivity extends Activity {

// Instance Variables
EditText userNumber;
Button factorButton;
TextView resultsField;
int factorResults = 1;
int userInt = 0;  // This comes out if using Integer userInt

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    resultsField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultsField);
    factorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.factorButton);
    userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNumber); 
                // userNumber is also the name of the EditText field.

    // userInt = Integer.parseInt(userNumber.getText().toString());

    // Integer userInt = new Integer(userNumber.getText().toString());

    resultsField.append("\n" + String.valueOf(userInt)); 
               //Later, this will be factorResults, not userInt.
               // Right now, I just want it to put something on the screen.      

}   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to parse the int in your `onCreate` method, which occurs before the user has a chance to enter anything into the `EditText`.  Hence the exception from trying to parse an empty string.

You'll have to either make a button to press, which will then parse the int out of the `EditText`, or attach a listener to the `EditText` that will parse it when something is typed into it.